# Using NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore in both app extension and main application

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, icloud, ios-app-extension, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I have set up App Groups and am using `NSUserDefaults initWith suiteName` in order to allow my app and my extension to access the same set of preferences. I would now like to replace that implementation with one that will sync those preferences over iCloud (if they have iCloud enabled).

I have read up on on `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` which seems to be exactly what I need. However, the documentation states "An app must always use the default iCloud key-value store object to get and set values. This store is tied to the unique identifier string your app provides in its entitlement requests." That causes me to believe if I adopt this, the app extension won't be accessing the same store as the main app. Nothing was said in the Extensions Programming Guide about sharing such a store, it only mentioned a solution that allows access to the same preferences but only stored locally on that device.

How would one implement iCloud synchronization of simple preferences that can also be accessed from that app's extensions?

Another quick question, has anything changed for iOS 8? I know major changes have come in regards to iCloud API but perhaps they didn't touch the simple preferences syncing, only implemented iCloud Drive?

Comment: I'm using `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` in both my app and my extension. I can read and write to the store successfully, but it seems like they are using different stores, though I configured their iCloud entitlements identically. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @floschliep I actually might have an idea. Do you have Allow Full Access enabled? Can you post your code in an answer, I'll see if I can make it work.

Comment: I already solved my problem, which was the configuration of the entitlements file. The main app's icloud id started with the team id whilst the extension's icloud id didn't (though the actual id was the same). So I just prefixed the id in all files and it worked.

Comment: @floschliep So they are using the same "stores", you can access the same values in the extension and app, and it syncs across devices? If you can post how you implemented that as an answer that would be awesome.

Comment: Yes, both my app and extension are using the same store and sync works. I didn't need any code changes and I already said what I did in the last comment.

Comment: Took me ages to get this working, as my extension kept using a different iCloud container to the app, so it wouldn't see changes made in the app, even when the key for NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore was set the same.

What worked for me was to enable CloudKit for the extension  (although my extension doesn't use it) on the extension's "Capabilities" tab, then choose the iCloud container that the app was using instead of default. This makes them look in the same place.

That solved the problem, and works using automatic code signing

Answer (score 20):

I recently encounter the same issue, I share my solution here, hopefully it can help someone.

`com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier` must be same between main app and extension app.

If you create an extension app (today extension), you will have 2 `.entitlements` files, one is for main app, the other one is for extension app.

You can find the value of `com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier` from both `.entitlments` files. You need to make sure both **values** are **same**.

I was using `$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)` for both `.entitlements` files, which is wrong. Because `$(CFBundleIdentifier)` is bundle id, it's actually different value for main app and extension app.

The fix is using hard coded bundle id: `$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.youcompnay.app`.

Comment: worked for me, thanks. However, I need to change the kvstore id manually after debugging since my main app has two bundle ids. one for debug and one for production.

Comment: For anyone else wondering: you configure this **in the Entitlement file** itself, not the Signing & Capabilities tab.